# Intent service can't be started in background

Tags: android, geolocation, android-pendingintent, background-service, activity-transition

In my android app I want to detect activity change from **still** to **walking** and start tracking location, regardless of the state of the app (in background or shut down completely).

I was able to create location tracking service which works while app in background by making it a foreground service (showing notification), but I have not been able to start tracking based on activity detection.

This is fragment of code of `IntentService`, which supposed to start location tracking service, after receiving intent with activity transition detected:

```
class ActivityDetectionIntent : IntentService(TAG) {
    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        val i = Intent(this@ActivityDetectionIntent, LocationTracking::class.java)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            startForegroundService(i)
            // this followed by foregroundService call in LocationTracking service
        } else {
            startService(i)
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

> 2019-12-04 19:57:59.797 3866-15015/? W/ActivityManager: Background start not
>   allowed: service Intent { cmp=com.anatoliymakesapps.myapplication/.ActivityDetectionIntent
>    (has extras) } to com.anatoliymakesapps.myapplication/.ActivityDetectionIntent 
>   from pid=-1 uid=10377 pkg=com.anatoliymakesapps.myapplication startFg?=false

I wonder if I miss something obvious, or maybe this whole approach is wrong and I need to try something else? Any piece of advice to achieve the desired result is appreciated.

I tried changing `IntentService` to `JobIntentService` but it made no difference, error looks the same.

Comment: do u have this in manifest    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

Comment: yes, I do have this in manifest, both ActivityDetectionIntent and LocationTracking Services also in manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out intent service can not be started directly, but with help of broadcast receiver it can be achieved indirectly.

This is what I used instead of `IntentService`:

```
class ActivityTransitionBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "got activity transition signal")
        val i = Intent(context, LocationTrackingService::class.java)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            startForegroundService(context, i)
        } else {
            context.startService(i)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = ActivityTransitionBroadcastReceiver::class.java.simpleName
    }

}
```

manifest:

```
        <receiver android:name=".ActivityTransitionBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true" />
```